# How to Change Bootstrap Login to logout In asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap with ASP.net masterpage so the navbar is in the masterpage how do I change the login Icon to logout after User login and vise versa.
please provide some examples

Comment: Without looking at your code we'll be guessing

Answer (score 0):

you can add class or image to links:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
     // ...here you have a link to logut - you can add class or image or whatever you need
     <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
     // ...
} 
else 
{
     // ... here you have a link to log-in - you can add class or image or whatever you need
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
     // ...
}
```